# Join MongoDB subdocuments in same parent document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given this `Orders` collection:

```js
// Order documents
[
  {
    _id: "order_123",
    items: [
      { _id: "item_123", type: "T-Shirt" },
      { _id: "item_234", type: "Hoodie" },
      { _id: "item_345", type: "Hat" },
    ],
    refunds: [
      {
        _id: "refund_123",
        items: ["item_123", "item_234"],
      },
      {
        _id: "refund_234",
        items: ["item_345"],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Is it possible to map `refunds.items` -> `items._id`, allowing us to filter by `type`?

This is how we currently get the refund sub-documents:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        order: "$$ROOT",
        refunds: "$$ROOT.refunds",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$refunds",
  },
  {
    $project: {
      order: "$order",
      refund: "$refunds",
    },
  },
]);
```

Which gives us:

```
// Refund documents
[
  {
    refund: {
      _id: "refund_123",
      items: ["item_123", "item_234"],
    },
    order: { ... }, // The original order document
  },
  {
    refund: {
      _id: "refund_234",
      items: ["item_345"],
    },
    order: { ... }, // The original order document
  },
]
```

From here, we want to map up `refund.items` -> `order.items._id` to produce the following output:

```js
[
  {
    _id: "refund_123",
    items: [
      { _id: "item_123", type: "T-Shirt" },
      { _id: "item_234", type: "Hoodie" },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: "refund_234",
    items: [
      { _id: "item_345", type: "Hat" }
    ],
  },
]
```

Allowing us to filter refund documents by `type`.

Comment: Please show the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `$unwind` and `$filter`,

- `$unwind` deconstruct array `refunds`
- `$project` to show refund id in `_id`, and filter `items` that are in `refunds.items` array using `$filter`

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$refunds" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$refunds._id",
      items: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$items",
          cond: { $in: ["$$this._id", "$refunds.items"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NgJRwV8idin)